# mysql - a better way to change all empty strings to NULL in a large and frequently updated table?

Tags: mysql, string, null, formatting

Have a large table that will be getting updated with new records daily or weekly, that has a lot of formatting issues that have to be resolved once it's loaded... trimming, removing characters, etc. One of them is changing all the empty strings to null, and right now I just have an update statement that has a CASE WHEN listed for every single column (and there are many). It seems so inefficient and clunky... is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use them, then use a before insert or before update trigger on that table.  It will check if the new.field = '' and set its value to null.  Repeat for all columns.

This is the best way to ensure your database integrity.